# How to blank out returned variable values in text file using PowerShell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have text files with values I would like to blank out using a PowerShell script.

For example, there are the following variables and their corresponding values:

```
Customer FirstName = CHRISTINE
Customer LastName = TOWN
CRN = 211021815L
```

I would like the script to go through the contents of the file and replace the returned values so they appear as below:

```
Customer FirstName = ******
Customer LastName = ******
CRN = ******
```

Ideally, the number of asterisks will be the same for every returned value so that no information can be derived from it. As in, if the `Customer FirstName` returnd value is 8 characters, the number of asterisks should NOT match 8 characters. It should be arbitrary.

Note that I have seen an existing question asked that is similar but the person asks how to insert a variable value into a placeholder rather than replacing an already retured value. As the returned value within my text files are constantly changing, a different solution is needed.

I am very new to PowerShell but came up with something pretty basic below:

```
(Get-Content C:\Temp\Logs\logfile.log).replace('CRN = <REGEXPRESSIONHERE>', '*****') | Set-Content C:\Temp\Logs\logfile.log
```

Is there a nicer way to accommodate for more variables in the single line rather than having a line to replace the returned value for each variable that needs to be blanked out?

Comment: Don't forget to update your question with what you have already tried and how it didn't work.

Comment: Are the lines always formatted `<variable><whitespace>=<whitespace><value>`?  If so, a more general regular expression should work for you.  such as `"(\S+)\s*=\s*.+"` replaced with `"$1 = *****"`, or something similar.

Looking at it a little closer, you'll need to change more than just the regex...

Comment: Hello Glenn, yes, they are always formatted that way. I will try your recommendation. Thank you.

Comment: @ChristianTownsend there were issues with the regex in my comment above, so disregard that.  I added a suggestion below as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
( Get-Content .\logfile.log | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "(.+) = .+", "`$1 = ****" } ) | Set-Content .\logfile.log
```

I believe you have to allow `Get-Content` and `ForEach-Object` to complete before writing back to the same file.  That's the reason for the extra set of parentheses.

Comment: This is almost perfect. How can I specify in the script to only asterisk specific variables rather than all of them?

Comment: ( Get-Content C:\Temp\Logs\iforlog-with_PII.log | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "(CRN|FirstName|LastName) = .+", "`$1 = TESTING" } ) | Set-Content C:\Temp\Logs\iforlog-with_PII.log